# when to call navigator.registerProtocolHandler

Tags: javascript, html, eventhandler

I am trying to call navigator.registerProtocolHandler while loading my website so that it sets my mail app as the default mailTo handler. If it is working, it will show a dialog asking user whether to allow or block such action.

What I found is that the registerProtocolHandler only works on a user action, such as click, but not on non-user event, such as document.ready, please see this example: `https://jsfiddle.net/eurkmgab/4`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 navigator.registerProtocolHandler(
            'mailto',
            'https://fiddle.jshell.net/mail/deeplink/compose/?mailtouri=%s',
            'My Mail App Web Mailto'
        );
        
        
  $("button").click(function(){
     navigator.registerProtocolHandler(
            'mailto',
            'https://fiddle.jshell.net/mail/deeplink/compose/?mailtouri=%s',
            'My Mail App Web Mailto'
        );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
test for register protocal handler
</p>
<button>Register protocal handler</button>

</body>
</html>
```

the dialog is not shown on document ready event, but shows if you click the button.

So I am wondering if this is the original behavior of registerProtocolHandler.Is there anyway to make it work on non user triggered event? Thanks for the help!

Comment: For me just going [there](https://jsfiddle.net/gvfz4cpx/) without interaction shows both FF's prompt and Chrome's <♢> near the address bar.

Comment: @Kaiido ah....I didn't notice this. It works the same way for me. Thanks!